# Needing some explanation about OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I know what the function `ObRegisterCallbacks` does, and I need an explanation about the callback altitude, how can I specify the priority for my driver is higher than another driver? Making it call my registered callback to strip handles. I'm making an anti-cheat system right now and I really need this.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=35413

Comment: And what do you do when the next person comes along and wants their driver to be higher priority than all other drivers? And the person after that? And the person after that? Pretty soon nothing works. If you have this requirement, you're doing something wrong.